# Show logo if site has scrolled

Tags: javascript, css

I have a header with a logo. This logo should appear only if the site has been scrolled.

I tried this in javascript:

```
if(document.getElementById("div").scrollTop != 0){
  document.write("<img src='logo.jpg'>");
}
```

But this did not work.

How to achieve it?

Comment: "*It hasn't to be javascript.*" ... unfortunately at this point in time, using javascript is the only real reliable way to get it done cross-browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `window.addEventListener('scroll', callback)` and then set the value `"block"` to the `img`'s property.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  if (document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].scrollTop > 5) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('imgHeader')[0].style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementsByClassName('imgHeader')[0].style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
.imgHeader {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: none;
}

div {
  height: 1000px;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header><img class="imgHeader" src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg" /></header>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```js
$(document).on("scroll", function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 5) {
    $(".below-top-header").addClass("show-class");
  } else {
    $(".below-top-header").removeClass("show-class");
  }
});
```

```css
.content {
  height: 500px;
}

.show-class {
  position: fixed;
  display: block !important;
}

.hide-class {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="below-top-header hide-class">
    Image
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why using jQuery ?

Comment: Because she/he can.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I think you must use some JavaScript to make it work like you want.

Here is an easy snippet to show the principle I used:

- Start with the logo already in the `html`, but with `display: none` in its CSS,
- Use `window.addEventListener('scroll', callback)` to change `display: none` to `display: block` when the page is scrolled down (i.e. `document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0`).

```js
var logo = document.getElementById('logo');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0) {
        logo.style.display = 'block';
  }else logo.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
#logo {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background: #aaa;
}

#page {
  background: #ddd;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div id='logo'><img src='http://placekitten.com/200/50'></div>
<div id='page'>Start of page<br>Try to scroll down</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an scrollListener to the window in order to execute code when the user scrolls.
Your code only gets executed on page load.

Informations on Eventlisteners: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    //do something as soon as the window was scrolled
});
```

Be aware that the event will be triggered each time the user scrolls.